# Can I wear a tin foil hat on a commercial flight?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security

Reading [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/124131/21265) got me thinking... Suppose someone is extremely  paranoid, would they be allowed to board a flight wearing a tin foil hat?

Obviously, this is a hypothetical question, but I wasn't able to find an answer to it. Travel seems to be the best place to do it.

It seems like [pilots are allowed](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/news/ryanair/Ryanair-pilot-poses-in-tinfoil-hat-and-calls-passengers-morons/) to do it. But are passengers?

Comment: You'd have to take it off at the metal detector. **And what if that is where they emit the mind-control rays!**

Comment: Because it's metal, or because it's a hat?

Comment: Chuck, is that you?

Comment: Definitely because it's metal. Also because it's a strange hat.

Comment: Beware: [Tin Foil Hats Actually Make it Easier for the Government to Track Your Thoughts](http://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2012/09/tin-foil-hats-actually-make-it-easier-for-the-government-to-track-your-thoughts/262998/). Or maybe that's just what they want you to think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can wear it, as [even the TSA](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/prohibited-items) doesn't have anything against tin foil in any forms. Of course you'd have to take it off for the metal detector, but that's it.

Comment: TSA may not have an issue with it as long as they can search it, but it's entirely possible the airline or the crew will be concerned about you. It's certainly conceivable that they either just ignore it or ask you a few questions to see if you otherwise seem more-or-less normal, but this also sounds like the setup for a headline: "man in tinfoil hat kicked off flight."

Comment: @ZachLipton you could put tin foil under a regular cap, so that it looks normal.